# KMP string searching in Haskell - non exhaustive pattern

Tags: string, algorithm, haskell

Hi I tried to implement the KMP string searching algorithm in Haskell. But when I try to run the function kmp it only says "non exhaustive pattern" for this function. No matter how much I try to correct it. I thought I had every possible outcome covert. Maybe I'm just blind but i hope someone could help me here.:

```
prefix :: String -> [Int]
prefix p = hprefix p p 0

hprefix :: String -> String -> Int -> [Int]
hprefix [] (i:is) int = []
hprefix (p:ps) (i:is) int | (length(i:is)) - (length(p:ps)) == 0 = 0:(hprefix ps (i:is) 0)
                          | p == (head(drop (int) (i:is))) = (int+1):(hprefix ps (i:is) (int+1))
                          | p == i = 1:(hprefix ps (i:is) 1)
                          | otherwise = 0:(hprefix ps (i:is) 0)

hkmp :: String -> String -> [Int]
hkmp p [] = error "leerer Text"
hkmp [] t = error "leeres Pattern"
hkmp p t = kmp p p (take (length p) t) t t

kmp :: String -> String -> String -> String -> String -> [Int]
kmp p (a:as) (b:bs) (t:ts) o | o == [] = error "leerer Text"
                               | p == [] = error "leeres Pattern"
                               | (length p) > (length o) = error "Pattern größer als Text"
                               | (t:ts) == [] = []
                               | (a:as) == [] = ((length(o)) - (length (t:ts))):(kmp p p (take (length p) (drop (length p) (t:ts))) (drop (length p) (t:ts)) o)
                               | (b:bs) == [] = []
                               | a == b = (kmp p as bs (t:ts) o)
                               | (head(drop ((length p) - (length (a:as))) (prefix p))) == 0 = (kmp p p (take (length p) ts) ts o)
                               | otherwise = (kmp p (drop (head(drop ((length p) - (length (a:as))) (prefix p))) p) (take (length p) (drop (head(drop ((length p) - (length (a:as))) (prefix p))) (t:ts))) (drop (head(drop ((length p) - (length (a:as))) (prefix p))) (t:ts))  o)
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: When there is a non-exhaustive pattern it will tell you the pattern.  Please post the error.  Also, from a glance you can see `hprefix _ [ ]` does not have a definition.

Comment: *** Exception: KMP.lhs:(17,3)-(25,276): Non-exhaustive patterns in function kmp

Comment: hprefix is working. Its only kmp with problems

Comment: hprefix is partial as I said.  KMP is partial too - the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th arguments all need to be non-empty for it to be defined.

Comment: You cannot match an empty list with (t:ts) ... in particular (t:ts) == [] is always false

Comment: Enable warnings when you compile programs. At least `-W`, which includes `-Wincomplete-patterns`, that tells you what patterns you are missing.

Comment: Ah very important info. -W saved me and everything is working now! Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing patterns are *before* the guards.  `(a:as)` and the like can't match `[]`, even if you put a guard to that effect.  You should write it more like:

```hs
kmp _ _ _ _ []                          = error "leerer Text"
kmp [] _ _ _ _                          = error "leeres Pattern"
kmp p _ _ _ o | (length p) > (length o) = error "Pattern größer als Text"
kmp _ _ _ [] _                          = []
kmp _ _ _ [] _                          = []
kmp p [] _ t o                          = ((length o) - (length t))):(kmp p p (take (length p) (drop (length p) t)) (drop (length p) t) o)
kmp _ _ [] _ _                          = []
kmp p (a:as) (b:bs) t o | a == b        = (kmp p as bs t o)
kmp p (a:as) (b:bs) (t:ts) o | (head(drop ((length p) - (length (a:as))) (prefix p))) == 0 = (kmp p p (take (length p) ts) ts o)
kmp p a _ t o                           = (kmp p (drop (head(drop ((length p) - (length a)) (prefix p))) p) (take (length p) (drop (head(drop ((length p) - (length a)) (prefix p))) t)) (drop (head(drop ((length p) - (length a)) (prefix p))) t)  o)
```

Although you should really consider breaking this down further.  This is really hard to follow.

Answer (score 2):

With `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` or `-Wincomplete-patterns`, GHC will tell you what patterns you need to add to avoid this error:

```
test.hs:5:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘hprefix’:
        Patterns not matched:
            [] [] _
            (_:_) [] _
  |
5 | hprefix [] (i:is) int = []
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...

test.hs:17:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘kmp’:
        Patterns not matched:
            _ [] _ _ _
            _ (_:_) [] _ _
            _ (_:_) (_:_) [] _
   |
17 | kmp p (a:as) (b:bs) (t:ts) o | o == [] = error "leerer Text"
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

Comment: Thanks, I added: > hprefix [] (i:is) int = [] and > kmp p [] (b:bs) (t:ts) o = ((length(o)) - (length (t:ts))):(kmp p p (take (length p) (drop (length p) (t:ts))) (drop (length p) (t:ts)) o) 
> kmp p (a:as) [] (t:ts) o = [] 
> kmp p (a:as) (b:bs) [] o = [] but still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that your `hprefix` and `kmp` functions are not total, thus not exhaustive.

To see why, recall the first (and only) equation for `kmp`:

```
kmp p (a:as) (b:bs) (t:ts) o = ...
```

Here you are defining `kmp` enforcing the second, third and fourth argument to be non-empty strings. Hence, in order to make `kmp` total you have to cover these missing cases adding, for example, another equation to `kmp`'s pattern matching definition which will capture the cases where those strings are empty:

```
kmp p s1 s2 s3 o = ...
```

The compiler is simply stating that the program might crash at runtime if you call `kmp` with empty strings in the places above mentioned, as it is not defined.